# Scheduled shutdown with Gnome-scheduler - how to enter root psw

Tags: shutdown

I am trying to schedule my ubuntu 14 server to shutdown every evening at 12:01 using the /sbin/poweroff.

Since you need root to shutdown the command doesn't work.  If I put 'sudo' in front of the command it will prompt for the password but I am not on the server then so I cannot enter it.

How can I schedule a shutdown using gnome-scheduler so it enters the password automatically?

Comment: Have you tried running the scheduler with `sudo`? `sudo gnome-schedule`

Comment: I am using the GUI to run the scheduler.

Comment: If you run that command in a terminal window it will open the scheduler in the GUI, but the scheduled commands will be run as root.

Comment: Thanks...Are you saying to run the gnome-schedule as root, configure the shutdown job and then since I am running the schedule as root when the job runs it will run as root?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: I think that running gnome-scheduler as root is a bad idea. Type the wrong command and you can come back and have a non-functional system. Much better to enable poweroff command to be issued without password.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way to do this is a two-step process:

1) adding the command you want execute as root in `sudoers` so that your normal user can execute it without password. To do this, create a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/`; you can call it whatever you want, for example `my-settings`(1)(2):

```
sudo gedit /etc/sudoers.d/my-settings
```

with contents:

```
romano ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
romano ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff
```

(obviously, change `romano` with your normal user; if you do not need to suspend too, you can omit the first line). Now you have to make the file readable by root only:

```
sudo chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/my-settings
```

...and you are set. Now you should be able to run `sudo /sbin/poweroff` to shut off the machine and you will not be prompted for a password.

2) Add the command `sudo /sbin/poweroff` to your gnome scheduler or use it in your scripts.

I use it a lot to do a nightly backup with a command line of the style "my_backup_script; sudo /usr/sbin/pm-suspend` or after long commands (say, converting a video format and then poweroff).

There is a [Ubuntu page about the sudoers file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers), but it is not really up-to-date (it was written before the `sudo` utility had the ability to parse the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory), although the info there is still valid.

---

*Footnotes*

(1) note that this work in recent version of `sudo` (I mean, the availability of `/etc/sudoers.d` directory). You can check if it will work by looking at the file `/etc/sudoers; if it has the line (near the end)

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

it will work. Otherwise, you need to add the abovementioned lines directly to `/etc/sudoers` files; be careful and use `visudo`for that, because a broken `/etc/sudoers` file is one of the most difficult things to recover in Ubuntu systems.

If you edit the main files directly, be warned that it could get overwritten on updates.

(2) No dots allowed, so do not use an extension! See `/etc/sudoers.d/README` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not bored by security, you can prepare a shutdown script with:

```
echo <the_password_in_clear> |sudo -S /sbin/shutdown -P now
```

Then schedule it in cron (e.g. via gnome-schedule). The above line will inject the password (that's in readable format) into the sudo session for the shutdown. Use the `-P` option to keep the computer turnable on by bios schedule (I suppose you would like to turn the pc on&off in full auto).

Moreover, controlling the shutdown via the user script gives the possibility to include additional actions to be performed before the actual shutdown, without messing with system files.